# Form submission ignored by Javascript, but picked up by Flask

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have a form in my Flask app. I need the form submission to be mediated by Javascript (JS). The desired behavior is that on submission of the form, we get an immediate redirect, then JS talks to Flask, Flask sends a response, JS updates the DOM.

Problem: The form doesn't submit to JS. On submission, the text in the input box clears, and the page sits there. No errors log to the console

It appears to ignore my JS, though the `<script>` tags are in order, their placement in `layout.html` is correct, and `http://localhost:5000/static/index.js` displays the file. I inserted a `console.log` statement to test if the appropriate JS function was being fired. Got nothing. I enclosed everything in `$(document).ready()`. Still nothing. Placing a `method="post"` attribute in the `<form>` tag and a `name` attribute in the form's `input` box allowed me to submit directly to Flask, but I need it to go to JS. All of this is playing out on my machine, so no CORS. Where am I going wrong?

**Form that must go to JS then Flask**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="display-3">
        <strong>Create A Channel</strong>
    </div>
    <form id="channelForm" class="mt-4">
        <label for="channelName">Channel Name</label>
        <input id="channelName" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Enter Channel Name">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Create Channel">
    </form>
</div>
```

**Abbreviated JS**

```
document.querySelector('#channelForm').onsubmit = () => {
    console.log("here");
    window.location.href = 'messages.html';

    // other stuff that links to Flask route

};
```

**Flask route**

```
@app.route('/channels', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def channels():
    channelList = []
    if request.method == "POST":

        channel = request.form.get("channel")

        if not (channel is None) and not (channel in channelList):
            channelList.append(channel)
            print(channelList)
            return jsonify({"success": True, "channel":channelList})
        else:
            return jsonify({"success": False})

    else:
        return render_template("channels.html")
```

**Head section from layout.html**

```
<head>
    {% block head %}
    <!-- Bootstrap 4 -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Additional CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

**EDIT**
When I hit the button to submit the form, I see `"GET /static/index.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -` in the terminal. Still nothing in the console, but I thought a GET request was unusual, given I was hitting a button to submit a form. Was expecting POST.

Comment: I know you mentioned that you have a document ready and everything is in order, but I would check it all again. I just pasted the html and javascript into CodePen and the console.log came out just fine.

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: This is killing me. It's the second time someone else has tested out fine. I'm in the latest Chrome. The flask_sockets-io package is also running, which appears to screw absolutely everything up. Someone mentioned monkey patching. I'm looking for an example.

Comment: Just tried in Firefox. Still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your form is being submitted through HTTP protocol (traditional form submission) rather than JS. To prevent this, you need to stop your button click from submitting the form:

```
var form = document.querySelector('#channelForm'),
    button = form.querySelector('input.btn-primary');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log('process form data!');
})
```

Also, place your JavaScript include after your HTML inclusions, so the elements targeted by your JS are on the page when the JS loads.

Comment: Like this? 
  var form = document.querySelector('#channelForm'),
     button = form.querySelector('input.btn-primary');

  // channel creation
  form.onsubmit = () => {
   
   button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     console.log('process form data!');
   });
   
   console.log("here");
   window.location.href = 'messages.html';

Comment: Almost; like this: https://gist.github.com/duhaime/b15e9a2e2e2907b090a184a5e41aedbd

Comment: No change. I may have to nuke this from space, just to be sure, and start over. I'll keep playing with your suggestions though.

Comment: It is reading the js file, because it picked up a syntax error. It just skips all of the console logs and actual code.

Comment: @Ryan, when you make the changes above, do you see the message "move your js below your html" in your console? Are there console warnings or logs?

Comment: Well a syntax error will prevent your js from running! Remove all of your js (put it somewhere else for now) and just use mine then submit your form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179569/discussion-between-duhaime-and-ryan).

Comment: The syntax error occurred after I commented out prior JS for another page that worked. I had a stray parens. Fixed it and reran. Got nothing. None of your messages appeared in the console and no errors either. I'd love a nice error at this point.

Answer (score 0):

What might be happening is that the response from your server is quicker than you realize. You're not preventing the default onsubmit functionality, so you might not actually see the JS run in your console. To see this, you can try to turn on a preserve logs between navigations setting. But what you likely need is to prevent the default and then directly send your request to your server:

```
document.querySelector('#channelForm').onsubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
  ...
  // AJAX request to your server with your data
};
```

Comment: No change, but appreciate the attempt.